# Adding Redundancy to Win 2008 and SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, backup, redundancy

We have an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server running Email2Database and another SQL-based windows application.

There is a lot of critical data on this box and we need to make sure that we keep this data protected and build in redundancy to the server.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I need to do?

Comment: Data protection/preservation and system redundancy are two wholly different things in my book, so what is it that you need? Do you need to protect/preserve the data (backups, etc.) or do you need to build redundancy into the system (NIC teaming, etc.) or both?

Comment: 1st data protection/preservation, but 2nd - if that server goes down, we need it to failover to another one.

Answer (score 1):

Data protection is setting up proper backups.

As for high availability (failing over to another server) basically your two options within EC2 are Log Shipping or Database Mirroring (I'd recommend Database Mirroring).

Make sure that the two machines that you use are in different availability zone so that if there's a repeat of the zone failure nightmare than Amazon had a while back you keep a SQL Server up.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into setting up mirroring on AWS: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=245974